# Why do I not need to sign in the next time I use my app?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing an app for windows phone 8 where the user needs to log on, and then the app will post to the wall of the user.

I've basically got this figured out, but after the first log on, I haven't had to log in again. I tried deleting the browser data on the phone, checked my runtime directory, and tried to log out using FacebookClient.GetLogoutUrl and navigating to it, but it still thinks I'm logged in.

How is my login information being stored?

And once I figure that out, is there a good way to determine this at runtime so that my app can configure itself accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide the `GetLogoutURL` function with the user `access_token` .

try this method to get the **LogoutURL** and navigate to it :

```
public static string GetLogoutURL(string AccessToken)
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new { access_token = AccessToken, next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" });
    return logoutUrl.ToString();
}
```

use any hidden WebBrowser to do this navigation :

```
AnyWebBrowserControl.Navigate(GetLogoutURL(AccessToken));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because once generated, an access token is valid for 2 months. Even if the user logs out, you can still make requests to the API till the access token is valid.

`And once I figure that out, is there a good way to determine this at runtime so that my app can configure itself accordingly?`

Yes, you can check(at runtime) if the access token is valid or expired by looking for the `FacebookOAuthException`

Here's a good tutorial: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html